# Continuous Integration/ Unit testing in embedded C++ systems

Tags: unit-testing, embedded, continuous-integration, embedded-linux

What tools are generally used for unit testing and especially continuous integration for embedded systems?

I am especially thinking that you usually have to cross-compile and deploy, and also that you can't easily visualize the target platform.  Also it can be difficult to run test-code and frameworks.

What could I use too alleviate these difficulties?

(I think it should be some kind of dual targeting, where the build server runs its tests on a easier target)

Answer (score 9):

For unit testing, take a look at Unity.
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/unity/wiki
It is a really lightweight test harness (2 x .h and 1 x .c file) supported by Ruby scripts. We have been using in an embedded ARM7 target system for unit testing (redirecting test reporting over a serial port).
It is also supported by CMock for (surprise, surprise) Mocking. Even though not extensive, the great thing about these is they are so easy to use.
Regarding CI, then Hudson (now Jenkins) is very good if you're Linux based.
Also look at CppUTest and check out James Grenning's book "TDD for Embedded C" at http://renaissancesoftware.net/

Answer (score 7):

At work I use the embUnit framework:

http://embunit.sourceforge.net/embunit/index.html

The nice thing about this framework is, that it's lean. It does not require any external libraries (not even libc). You can hook your own output function with ease so if you work on a system where the only connection to the outside world is jtag or an UART, then embUnit will still work.

Answer (score 5):

I have used [RCUNIT](http://rcunit.sourceforge.net/) and [CANTATA++](http://www.ipl.com/products/tools/pt400.php) for unit testing embedded code on the PC. Any Nunit should easily integrate into any continuous test platform. We found it an lot easier to just simulate the hardware on the PC and only test on the target during final integration.

Hardware interface abstraction is crucial for unit testing embedded code on the PC. This works well with continuous integration since it is run on a pc with just the hardware access simulated. With a little effort we could test 95% of the code on a PC for continues integration.

You could also look at these questions:

- [Unit Testing C Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65820/34989)
- [Testing Frameworks for C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/437233/34989)
- [Unit Testing Embedded Software](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1061652/34989)

Comment: CANTATA++ link is broken; looks like current link is http://www.qa-systems.com/cantata.html.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen C(pp)unit used on a system that let you launch to the target via JTAG.

Helps to have console comms etc sorted.

But it can work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an open-source [tool](https://github.com/mw-sc/mw.test) for that, that is either a minimal test or can provide detailed information when run through the debugger.